# FOSElacticaBundle: failed to parse [geo_bbox] query. unexpected field [gte] [reason: all shards failed]

Tags: php, symfony, elasticsearch, foselasticabundle

I use FOSElasticaBundle's GeoBoundingBox [1] class to successfully populate a map of users in a given area. Now I want to add a criterion in order to only map users who were active within the last 10 minutes. So I add a mapping in `fos_elastica.yml` like

```yaml
types:
    user:
        mappings:
            id: ~
            username: ~
            firstName: ~
            lastName: ~
            email: ~
            location:
                type: geo_point
            lastActivityAt:
                type: date
...
```

I run `fos:elastica:reset` and `fos:elastica:populate`, just to be sure I have current results. Those commands run successfully. So far so good, I also clear the Symfony cache. I then add the following logic in the controller that I'm hitting with an AJAX call

```
$query = new GeoBoundingBox(
            'location',
            array(
                //top_left
                array(
                   'lat' => $data['north'],
                   'lon' => $data['west']
                ),
                //bottom_right
                array(
                    'lat' => $data['south'],
                    'lon' => $data['east']
                )
            )
        );

$earlier = new \DateTime('10 minutes ago');
$query->addParam('lastActivityAt', ['gte' => $earlier]);

$result = $this->get('fos_elastica.finder.app.user')->find($query);
...
```

That's where the trouble starts. I refresh the map in the browser, and in the network inspector, I now get the following error

> failed to parse [geo_bbox] query. unexpected field [gte] [reason: all shards failed]

I'm clearly doing something wrong here. I don't know much about Elasticsearch. How can I correctly use `Param::addParam()` to set this up?

[1] https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle

Comment: Can you add the query building steps? Also, can you dump the final JSON query before it gets sent to ES? I'm not familiar w/ FOS-EB but maybe using [this](https://elastica.io/api/5.3.0/classes/Elastica.QueryBuilder.html#method_query)?

Comment: Thanks, Joe. I have added a bit more of the query-building process. The `$query->addParam('lastActivityAt', ['gte' => $earlier]);` is the new part that breaks things. Everything worked before that was added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message suggests, you cannot add a datetime `range` query to a `geo_bounding_box` query. You'll need to wrap both in a so-called boolean query.

You'd need something along the lines of:

```php
$boolQuery = new \Elastica\Query\BoolQuery();

$bboxQuery = new GeoBoundingBox(
            'location',
            array(
                //top_left
                array(
                   'lat' => $data['north'],
                   'lon' => $data['west']
                ),
                //bottom_right
                array(
                    'lat' => $data['south'],
                    'lon' => $data['east']
                )
            )
        );
$boolQuery->addMust($bboxQuery);

$rangeQuery = new Elastica\Query\Range();
        $earlier = new \DateTime('2 hours ago');
        $earlierString = substr($earlier->format(DateTimeInterface::ISO8601), 0, -5);
        $timeZone = substr($earlier->format(DateTimeInterface::ISO8601), -5, 5);
        $rangeQuery->addField(
            'lastActivityAt',
            [
                'time_zone'=> $timeZone,
                'gte' => $earlierString,
                'lte' => 'now'
            ]
        );
$boolQuery->addMust($rangeQuery);

$result = $this->get('fos_elastica.finder.app.user')->find($boolQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks, Joe! I feel like we're getting close to an answer that I can mark as the accepted one. Now I get the following error: `[range] query does not support [date]`. Is there perhaps another query type I should try?

Comment: No prob. Can you try `NumericRange()` instead of `Range()`?

Comment: Never mind -- got it working and made a small edit to your answer to show the solution that worked. I'll accept this as the best solution. Thanks again!